# Passwordless SSH Local Port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, rhel6

I have setup `SSH Local Port forwarding` successfully with the below command

```
 ssh rex@server-001 -L 0.0.0.0:4122:node-x3:22
```

Now I am trying to do a passwordless access . For that I am using below command

```
 ssh -i /home/rex/.ssh/id_rsa rex@server-001 -L 0.0.0.0:4122:node-x3:22
```

But it is asking or password. How to make passwordless work in Port forwarding.

Comment: Is there a password on your private key or is the server not accepting your key and asking for a password instead? check from your client with one or `-v` debug switches or look at the server logs.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue. It seems we have setup the passwordless access on the server itself from where I am firing the `ssh` command rather than on the destination server for local port forwarding to work .

Answer (score 2):

You need to authorize the key on the target host. You can do this manually (by putting the public part of the key in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`) or by using the `ssh-copy-id` helper program.

```
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub rex@server-001
```

If you do it manually, you'll need to check the permissions on the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file - see the man page for more details but, as a general rule, it should be:

```
drwx------ .ssh
-rw------- .ssh/authorized_keys
```

If that doesn't work, add a `-v` (for verbose) to the ssh command used to log in and see what it's complaining about.